Restore previous value or unset environment variable without subshell
This is almost the same (BUT NOT THE SAME!) as this question. I want to save and restore a single environment variable, and leave it unset if it was unset. But unlike that question I don't have the option of using a subshell because the "middle" command sets some other environment variables I want to keep. I.e.
$ cat ./myenv.sh
export SOME_VAR=1
export OTHER_VAR=1
$ save SOME_VAR
$ source ./myenv.sh
$ restore SOME_VAR

After this SOME_VAR should be unset and OTHER_VAR should be 1. How can I do this?

So save the value of SOME_VAR, or save it is unset, and then restore. What have you tried?

saved_SOME_VAR=$SOME_VAR at the beginning, and SOME_VAR=$saved_SOME_VAR at the end.

Doesn't work if SOME_VAR as unset.

Not fully understand what you trying to do but there is an option to create readonly vars:
declare -r SOME_VAR=1 Now if you try to write to this var or source it, it won't change.

export is often misunderstood and abused, and seems to have no bearing at all on this question.  Perhaps deleting the exports from the input file would simplify things.

This is arguably a duplicate of questions about reliably saving and restoring the  IFS special variable.  See Bash Pitfalls #49 (OIFS="$IFS"; ...; IFS="$OIFS") and Is it a sane approach to "back up" the $IFS variable?.

@pjh: That is a totally different question.

@Ivan: Not a bad idea but in my case I want the variable to remain mutable.

@WilliamPursell: yeah I don't think export affects the question at all; just happened that my use case needs export.

This may do what you want:
SOME_VAR='' source ./myenv.sh

The SOME_VAR environment variable is set (to empty) just for the source command.  Previous settings of SOME_VAR (including being unset) are restored after the source command completes.

Neat trick! I guess you can do SOME_VAR="$SOME_VAR" source ./myenv.sh if you want the value to be visible inside myenv.sh.


The simplest approach is to wrap the code in a function and use the local builtin. (Bash uses dynamic local scope, so this has exactly the behavior you describe, of saving the original variable and then restoring it.)
If that's not an option for some reason, then:

To test if a variable named SOMEVAR is set, you can write e.g. ${SOMEVAR+yes}, which expands to yes if it's set and otherwise to the empty string. (You can save that in a variable named was_SOMEVAR_set, and later write if [[ "$was_SOMEVAR_set" ]].)
If it is set, then of course you can save its value in another variable to restore from later.
If it's not set, then you'll use the unset builtin to restore that once you're done.




I think this is correct. It requires Bash 4.2 (which is very old). It also clobbers SAVED_SOME_VAR but I think that's unavoidable and not likely to be an issue.
if [[ -v SOME_VAR ]]; then
    SAVED_SOME_VAR="$SOME_VAR"
else
    unset SAVED_SOME_VAR
fi

...

if [[ -v SAVED_SOME_VAR ]]; then
    export SOME_VAR="$SAVED_SOME_VAR"
    unset SAVED_SOME_VAR
else
    unset SOME_VAR
fi


If you don't want to spend another variable, you can also print the value to a file and restore it from there.

An alternative that works with older versions of Bash (tested with Bash 3.2) is to use [[ ${SOME_VAR+_} ]] && saved_some_var=$SOME_VAR || unset saved_some_var to save the value (or unset status) of SOME_VAR and use [[ ${saved_some_var+_} ]] && SOME_VAR=$saved_some_var || unset SOME_VAR to restore it (or unset it again).
